# mcc -B option with nojvm or optimization flag

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I am using `mcc` compiler to generate C shared library as follows. I want to use the `O3` option but can't use it directly.

I tried all these options below:

1. `mcc -O3 -B csharedlib:libmyc foo.m`
2. `mcc -R -nojvm -B csharedlib:libmyc foo.m`

but I was not successful.

I am not using JVM so thought of not using JVM. Does it improves the performance? 
Is there any other simple way to improve the performance out of cshared lib?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you're question isn't very clear, can you clarify it a bit?

Comment: i want to optimize the c library created by mcc complier. i was looking for available options to optimize it. i tried first with O3 and the -R -nojvm. but not successfull i got errors. My question is, is there any other optimization ways?

Answer (score 0):

mcc use mbuild to compile the C code. Hence, you can change the compiler options in the matlabroot /bin/mbuildopts.sh file. If you do not have access to this file, you can make your own personal copy and change that instead. In matlab, run

```
mbuild -setup
```

Choose the mbuildopts.sh file from the options list. It will be copied to your home directory. MATLAB will tell you the path. You can now modify the gcc options to your liking.